# Reading the ID of an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I want to use the ID of a certain element and convert it to a javascript variable to then be used in an Ajax request. Here is what outputs on to my HTML page via ajax, multiple times depending on the search.

```
while ( $row ) {

  echo "<div class='reviewdiv'>";
  echo "<h4>Name: " . $row[name] . "</h4>";
  echo "<h4>Type: " . $row[type] . "</h4>";
  echo "<h4>Country: " . $row[country] . "</h4>";
  echo "<h4>Region: " . $row[region] . "</h4>";
  echo "<h4>Added by: " . $row[username] . "</h4>";
  echo "<h4>Description: " . $row[description] . "</h4>";
  echo "<h4>Review This Place:</h4>";
  echo "<textarea name='review' class='userreview'></textarea>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='review' value='" . $row[ID] . "'>";
  echo "<input type='button' value='Submit Review' onclick='reviewajaxrequest()'>";
  echo "<h4><a href='reviewresults.php?PlaceID=" . $row[ID] . "'>View reviews</a></h4>";
  echo "<h4><a href='recommend.php?PlaceID=" . $row[ID] . "'>Recommend this place</a></h4>";
  echo "</div>";

  $row = $results->fetch();

}
```

What I want to do is grab $row[ID] from this and have it as a javascript variable, so it can then be passed into another script using Ajax. The function looks like this:

```
function reviewajaxrequest() {

  var xhr3 = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr3.addEventListener("load", resultsReturnedReview);
      xhr3.open("GET", "reviewadded.php?user_review=" + reviewbox + "&place_id=" + id);
      xhr3.send();

}
```

I want the variables "review box" and "id" to be defined if it is in the same result as the button that is clicked to trigger the function, which sends them both to another script. Any help please?

Comment: You could add a data-id= attribute to the button. then (in jQuery) inside the function, you can get the value using $(this).attr('data-id')

Comment: and what about passing the value of the textarea through as well? Because when I defined it before by ID it always brought it from the first one on the page

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one element on a page with the same ID. They are supposed to be unique. Although you can use arrays, it makes it harder to reference something by ID in Javascrpt.

Comment: So how would I pass the value of the textarea through?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, this will work.

Change the code for the review button to this:

```
echo "<input type='button' value='Submit Review' data-id='".$row['ID']."' onclick='reviewajaxrequest()'>";
```

Then change your function to this:

```
function reviewajaxrequest() {
    var xhr3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var txtarea = $(this).parent().child('textarea[name=review]').val();
    xhr3.addEventListener("load", resultsReturnedReview);
    xhr3.open("GET", "reviewadded.php?user_review=" + reviewbox + "&place_id=" + id + "&name=" + txtarea);
    xhr3.send();
}
```

Also, in your other references to $row, be sure to quote the index.

Comment: and what about passing the value of the textarea through as well? Because when I defined it before by ID it always brought it from the first one on the page

Comment: You should be able to do that easily in the function that makes the AJAX call. Just give it a unique ID like "txt_name" . $row['id'] Or you can use the $(this).parent().child('textarea') type of syntax to find a text area in the same div (or same row in a table for that matter). Just make the selector in child unique to the item you want.

Comment: See the change I made to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic example of use a [`data-` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-%2A) and plain JavaScript.

```php
'<input id="review" type="button" data-id="' . $row[ 'ID' ] . '" value="Submit Review">';
```

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll( '.review' );

btns.forEach( function ( btn, i, arr ) {

  btn.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
    alert( 'ID: ' + this.dataset.id );
  } );

} );
```

```html
<input class="review" type="button" data-id="123" value="Submit Review">
<br>
<input class="review" type="button" data-id="456" value="Submit Review">
```

If `dataset` is not available or you want a bit more browser support you can use `getAttribute()`:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector( '#review' );

btn.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
  alert( 'ID: ' + btn.getAttribute( 'data-id' ) );
} );
```

```html
<input id="review" type="button" data-id="123" value="Submit Review">
```

FWIW I wouldn't inline event handlers. It's not a proper separation of concerns. Attach the handler to the element via JS.

Comment: I can't give the input an ID because more than one will appear on the same page, meaning it will only ever read the first one

Comment: @DanielMann that's just an example. Use whatever selector you want to retrieve the button.

Comment: data-id and id are different things. The id might be xyz123 while the data-id='123'

Comment: @DanielMann I've updated my answer to use a class that handles multiple buttons.